# CSS - Adjust viewport zoom based on media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a website that I need to scale for different screen resolutions. So I decided to use media queries to change the zoom level based on screen resolution like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
  html {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
    zoom: 0.75;
    zoom: 75%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  html {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
    zoom: 0.75;
    zoom: 75%;
  }
}
```

The results are as follows:

**1. 10920x1080 resolution** (No zoom. This is the intended scale that I need to replicate for other screen sizes)
[image]

**2. 1366x768 resolution** (Without media queries and zoom)
[image]

**3. 1366x768 resolution** (With media queries and 75% zoom css applied)
[image]

I achieved the required scaling with the media queries and the zoom combination but the problem here is the viewport does not scale accordingly and remains at the original level. (refer image 3. Notice the awkward white space at the bottom, *outside* of the viewport). If I change the window zoom using Ctrl + the view port adjusts accordingly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that [`zoom` is non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom)

Comment: if you're going to go this route drop `zoom` and just use `transform` to scale dom elements. Instead of scaling your entire html, just apply styling to necessary elements. ie: `body > * { transform: scale(0.75, 0.75); }`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll definitely look into that option in the long term but right now I need a quick fix to scale the app to lower resolution screens; Do you have any suggestions on how I could work around the viewport issue mentioned in the question?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the screen to scale according to device width and then zoom out to 75%, you should use the viewport meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.75">`

---

Media queries are for resizing content separately for different viewport widths, not for uniformly scaling content adaptive to screen widths. In your case `@media screen and (max-width: 1366px)` already covers `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)`.

But since you have a second declaration for `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)`, the screens below 1024px width will use that declaration than `@media screen and (max-width: 1366px)`.

In your case both have the same declaration, making them redundant.